# My name was published on abstract but my name was not published on the final manuscript?

Tags: publications, postdocs, paper-submission, authorship, abstract

Can I send a letter to the editor and get my name published on the paper if my name was published on the abstract but not the final accepted manuscript. How should I best handle this sensitive situation.

Comment: Can you please be a bit more precise? How can a name be on an abstract but not on a paper?

Comment: Somebody removed your name. Was it a co-author or an error by the journal?

Comment: Hi Theoretician. The abstract was published for a conference called SNO and the abstract is publicly available. It was published before the final submission of the full manuscript. In other words my name was taken out in the final manuscript.

Comment: Hi Buffy. I was listed as 3rd author on the abstract and removed completely from the final accepted paper.

Comment: Who submitted the final full manuscript ? Do you know ?

Comment: Yes it was the PI in the lab where I was working. It does not seem like a mistake. It was the same PI who submitted the original abstract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume it's a mistake and ask the editor what happened.

If it's not a mistake ... then, well, cross that bridge when you get there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and I totally agree by the way. In a worst case scenario would I likely get my name listed on the final manuscript or should I not get my hopes up.

Comment: @WizKid it would be a serious breach of publication ethics if the journal removed your name after the manuscript was accepted, without confirming with you first. So unless there is something really unusual going on that you've not described, you should expect your name to be listed.

Comment: Hi Allure, the publication of the abstract was with a separate journal. They later published the full manuscript to a different journal without including my name. I can prove my name was on the original abstract describing the project but the final submission to a different journal did not include my name. I hope that helps make things a little clearer.

Comment: "They later published..." Who is the "they" here? The publisher of both or your co-authors?

Answer (score 5):

If it was the journal that made an error then they can correct it, and you can ask. But that seems very unlikely. It is more likely that the PI that submitted the paper made a change in the text of the document submitted. That may have been either a choice or a mistake. If the article was published as submitted then the journal isn't likely to change it without permission of the submitter.

If it was a choice, and you have to ask the PI to learn if that was the case, then you are due at least an answer as to why. If you dispute the answer when given then you can defend your authorship position to the PI and (see below) to the journal.

I would guess that you will have to eventually speak to the PI. But you can start with questions, not demands.

In a serious dispute, which isn't good for a student to engage in, you can demand that the journal retract the paper if you have a valid claim to authorship. Such things rarely turn out well and fighting with a PI, especially a supervisor, is seldom satisfactory in its outcome. You probably cannot demand that the journal add your name without the permission of all authors, including the PI.

Comment: Thank you buffy for your answer. I really appreciate the advice.